# SWING - JTextArea fit text

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

I'm trying to set the size of a JTextArea to surround the text.
Right now I have this

```
package messagebubble;


import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;


public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

private JPanel msgHoldingPanel = new JPanel();


public MainPanel() {

    JTextArea msg2 = new JTextArea();
    msg2.setLineWrap(true);
    msg2.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    msg2.setText("ola tudo bem ");



    msgHoldingPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(msgHoldingPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    msgHoldingPanel.add(msg2);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(msgHoldingPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

}


private static void createAndShowGui() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainPanel");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new MainPanel());
    frame.setSize(400, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Which shows this

[image: Output]

I want it to look like this

[image: Output2]

Which I can do by adding the following lines

```
msg2.setMaximumSize(msg2.getPreferredSize());
msg2.setAlignmentX(0);
```

But if I set a longer message it doesn't show it all. I want it to be as wide as the widest part of the text.

Comment: Would it be OK for you to change the layout of the `msgHoldingPanel` to a `new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT)`? It would work that way.

Comment: I'm trying to make a messaging app and I want new messages to show under the previous one, that's the reason for the BoxLayout. Also, in FlowLayout when the text wraps it shrinks the width of the textarea.

Comment: Well usually messaging apps have a single text area for entering messages. Then there is a display area for received/sent messages. This way you actually know what the final length of the message will be so you can better do calculations. For example you might initially set the wrap turned off. Then the preferred size calculation might get the preferred size and compare it to the width of the parent container. When the preferred with is greater, than you turn line wrapping on and revalidate to get the new preferred size.

Comment: @camickr I already had all those components, this is just the message view, but that's a great idea. Although I'm not sure it's possible because the size of any container in SWING is 0 before it's drawn

Comment: @camickr nevermind, that worked perfectly, thank you so much!